# How to add Serializable attributes in all entities generated by Entity Framework 5.0

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using EF 5.0 to generate POCO entities and using it in a seperate Data Access layer

I want to tag all the entities [Serializable]

How to modify template to add Serializable attribute?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Following are the steps to do so:

1) Open the ModelName.Entity.tt file

2) Locate following string in this file

```
<#=Accessibility.ForType(entity)
```

3) Write [Serializable] above this line, so the code will look like this

```
[Serializable] 
<#=Accessibility.ForType(entity)
```

Save the file , open the entity file, you can see that it has the desire tag written, you don't even have to generate entities again.

Answer (score 18):

If you don't want to edit the template, you can also do this in a separate code file - because of the convenience of `partial` classes. So if the types here are `Foo`, `Bar` and `Baz` in the `My.Namespace` namespace, you can create a *separate* file in the same project, with:

```
using System;
namespace My.Namespace {
    [Serializable] partial class Foo {}
    [Serializable] partial class Bar {}
    [Serializable] partial class Baz {}
}
```

This will then be merged with the generated half, applying the `[Serializable]` attribute. It will also allow you to add your own methods to the types, or to provide the body for any `partial` method implementations that the template declares.

I should, however, caution you: `[Serializable]` suggests you are using `BinaryFormatter`; this is *not* necessarily a good candidate. It would be preferable to look at contract-based serializers. I would be very surprised if the EF template did not already have the option to output attributes for `DataContractSerializer` (specifically, `[DataContract]`/`[DataMember]`). `BinaryFormatter` can be very problematic as you version your software.

Comment: +1 for the warning, Thanks for the alternative approach. However I find it difficult to write line per type, also I have to remember to add additional line every time I add new type to Model.

Comment: @ImranRizvi well, since you'll *obviously* (cough) also be adding new serialization integration tests every time you add a type that needs to be serialized, it will very quickly show when there is a problem. Obviously ;p You could also add a test that finds all of your POCO / DTO types via reflection, and checks for the attribute / `IsSerializable` flag.

Answer (score 12):

if you use entity framework 5.0 or above
Add [Serializable] tag between this code:

```
<#=codeStringGenerator.UsingDirectives(inHeader: false)#>

[Serializable]

<#=codeStringGenerator.EntityClassOpening(entity)#>
```

Comment: @nazimhatipoglu thank you. I added [DataContract] in that line and it actually added the attribute to every class. But how to use System.Runtime.Serialization? 
And how to add [DataMember] to properties in the template?

Answer (score 10):

For Entity Framework 6, Add Serializable above this two parts at Model.tt

```
[Serializable]
Partial <#=Accessibility.ForType(complex)#>

[Serializable]
<#=codeStringGenerator.EntityClassOpening(entity)#>
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is what you do for EF 6 (at least);

In your model.tt file, look for these lines:

```
    public string EntityClassOpening(EntityType entity)
    {
        return string.Format(
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            "{0} {1}partial class {2}{3}",
            Accessibility.ForType(entity),
            _code.SpaceAfter(_code.AbstractOption(entity)),
            _code.Escape(entity),
            _code.StringBefore(" : ", _typeMapper.GetTypeName(entity.BaseType))
        );
    }
```

Change it to these:

```
    public string EntityClassOpening(EntityType entity)
    {
        return string.Format(
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            "{0} " + Environment.NewLine + " {1} {2} partial class {3}{4}", 
            "[Serializable]", 
            Accessibility.ForType(entity),
            _code.SpaceAfter(_code.AbstractOption(entity)),
            _code.Escape(entity),
            _code.StringBefore(" : ", _typeMapper.GetTypeName(entity.BaseType)));
    }
```

Save your .tt file and your entity class files get `[Serializable]` Attribute on them.
Done.

Answer (score 1):

For EF 6 Try to find the following code in `.tt` file:

```
public string EntityClassOpening(EntityType entity)
{
    return string.Format(
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
        "{0} {1}partial class {2}{3}",
        Accessibility.ForType(entity),
        _code.SpaceAfter(_code.AbstractOption(entity)),
        _code.Escape(entity),
        _code.StringBefore(" : ", _typeMapper.GetTypeName(entity.BaseType))
    );
}
```

It has a string placeholder `("{0} {1}partial class {2}{3}")` you can change it to what ever you want

Comment: please refer how to answer on stackoverflow.